# Python Pandas: Counting the Frequency of unique values over all Columns

Tags: python, pandas, count, unique, frequency

I have a question, how does one count the number of unique values that occur within each column of a pandas data-frame?

Say I have a data frame named df that looks like this:

```
1    2    3    4    
a    yes  f    c
b    no   f    e
c    yes  d    h
```

I am wanting to get output that shows the frequency of unique values within the four columns. The output would be something similar to this:

```
Column    # of Unique Values
 1          3
 2          2
 3          2
 4          3
```

I don't need to know what the unique values are, just how many there are within each column.

I have played around with something like this:

```
df[all_cols].value_counts()
```

[all_cols] is a list of all the columns within the data frame. But this is counting how many times the value appears within the column.

Any advice/suggestions would be a great help. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could `apply` `Series.nunique`:

```
>>> df.apply(pd.Series.nunique)
1    3
2    2
3    2
4    3
dtype: int64
```

Or you could do a `groupby/nunique` on the unstacked version of the frame:

```
>>> df.unstack().groupby(level=0).nunique()
1    3
2    2
3    2
4    3
dtype: int64
```

Both of these produce a Series, which you could then use to build a frame with whatever column names you wanted.

Comment: Thank you so much this was exactly what I was looking for. I appreciate the help!

Comment: @da4l don't say thanks, just hit the upvote and accept buttons

Answer (score 2):

You could try `df.nunique()`

```
>>> df.nunique()
1    3
2    2
3    2
4    3
dtype: int64
```